# Two asp.net calendars for different cultures on the same page

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, calendar

I need two asp.net calendars for different cultures on the same page. I would like to use something like this

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = New CultureInfo("pl-PL")
```

Comment: If you need them on the same page you cannot change  `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture`, otherwise both would use this culture.

Comment: [THIS](http://lancezhang.wordpress.com/2009/01/09/change-culture-calendarextender/) might be helpful.

Comment: @Hoh: that's for the ajax-`CalendarExtender` not for the ASP.NET `Calendar`, it's also showing how to do it for a single culture and not for two on  one page with two calendars.

Comment: why do you want to set different cultures on the same page ?

Comment: I want to set with Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture, if possible?